# 1048576 bytes should have been written. Only 1044480 bytes written. Retrying for the remaining bytes

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bitnami

Wordpress is installed on Bitnami.
When I looked at the log records today, I saw the following errors;

```
    2020-08-16T18:26:15.618889Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 8901
2020-08-16T18:26:15.638134Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-08-16T18:26:16.203509Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012637] [InnoDB] 1048576 bytes should have been written. Only 1044480 bytes written. Retrying for the remaining bytes.
2020-08-16T18:26:16.205041Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012638] [InnoDB] Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2020-08-16T18:26:16.205188Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012639] [InnoDB] Write to file ./ibtmp1 failed at offset 7340032, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 1044480 were writ$
2020-08-16T18:26:16.208104Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012640] [InnoDB] Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
2020-08-16T18:26:16.208369Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012267] [InnoDB] Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
2020-08-16T18:26:16.208621Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012926] [InnoDB] Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary.
2020-08-16T18:26:16.210537Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2020-08-16T18:26:16.712427Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2020-08-16T18:26:16.714751Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-08-16T18:26:16.716022Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-08-16T18:26:16.734832Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld.bin: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enough disk space.

```
[InnoDB] Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
```

What is the out put of `df -hP` and `df -i` ?

Comment: Hello.

'df-hp : Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            233M     0  233M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  2.2M   47M   5% /run
/dev/xvda1       20G   19G  7.9M 100% /
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda15     124M  262K  124M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000'

Comment: Hello.
df -i: Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             59571   275   59296    1% /dev
tmpfs            61774   356   61418    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     1302528 69617 1232911    6% /
tmpfs            61774     1   61773    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            61774     2   61772    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            61774    17   61757    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda15          0     0       0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs            61774     4   61770    1% /run/user/1000

Comment: `/dev/xvda1 20G 19G 7.9M 100% /`. As Rabin mentioned, the disk is full. Please take a look at the cloud platform documentation to increase the disk space in your instance or remove some unused data to be able to start the services again. If you need help increasing the disk size, please let us know and we will share a Bitnami documentation guide with you (you will need to let us know first the cloud platform you are using to share the proper guide)